# Confidence Interval of Difference of Means between two datasets

Tags: r, dataset, confidence-interval

I'm working on two datasets, derrived fromm `cats`, an in-build R dataset.

```
> cats
    Sex Bwt  Hwt
1     F 2.0  7.0
2     F 2.0  7.4
3     F 2.0  9.5
4     F 2.1  7.2
5     F 2.1  7.3
6     F 2.1  7.6
7     F 2.1  8.1
8     F 2.1  8.2
9     F 2.1  8.3
10    F 2.1  8.5
11    F 2.1  8.7
12    F 2.1  9.8
...
137   M 3.6 13.3
138   M 3.6 14.8
139   M 3.6 15.0
140   M 3.7 11.0
141   M 3.8 14.8
142   M 3.8 16.8
143   M 3.9 14.4
144   M 3.9 20.5
```

I want to find the **99% Confidence Interval on the difference of means values** between the Bwt of Male and Female specimens (Sex == M and Sex == F respectively)

I know that `t.test` does this, among other things, but if I break up `cats` to two datasets that contain the `Bwt` of Males and Females, t.test() complains that the two datasets are not of the same length, which is true. There's only 47 Females in `cats`, and 87 Males.

Is it doable some other way or am I misinterpreting data by breaking them up?

EDIT:
I have a function suggested to me by an Answerer on another Question that gets the CI of means on a dataset, may come in handy:

```
ci_func <- function(data, ALPHA){
  c(
    mean(data) - qnorm(1-ALPHA/2) * sd(data)/sqrt(length(data)),
    mean(data) + qnorm(1-ALPHA/2) * sd(data)/sqrt(length(data))
    )
}
```

Comment: Why don't you actually add the code you tried

Comment: @Dason `t1 <- t.test( catsBwt_Female, catsBwt_Male, paired = TRUE )
Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length` is the extent of the code that I have tried, besides calculating the seperate 99% CIs for the mean of each dataset. I am new to statistics in general.

Comment: Why would you specify paired = TRUE when you aren't doing a paired t-test?

Comment: @Dason It is a mystery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should apply the t.test with the formula interface:

```
t.test(Bwt ~ Sex, data=cats, conf.level=.99)
```

Comment: Looks like I need to carefully read `t.test`'s documentation. Thank you for the quick and complete answer.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use the formula interface.  The main issue is that you were specifying a paired t-test when that didn't make sense for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `t.test`, if you really only interested in the difference of means, you can use:

```
DescTools::MeanDiffCI(cats$Bwt, cats$Sex)
```

which gives something like

```
 meandiff    lwr.ci    upr.ci 
-23.71474 -71.30611  23.87662
```

This is calculated with 999 bootstrapped samples by default. If you want more, you can specify this in the `R` parameter:

```
DescTools::MeanDiffCI(cats$Bwt, cats$Sex, R = 1000)
```